# Emulator tools, programming evironments for Iphone, smartphone, anyphone beginner

Tags: java, iphone, c++

I am completely new to phone programming. I am now a 3rd years student and lately becoming  quite interested in phone programming. I don't have much money to invest into tools, real phones, stuff like a commercial company does. I wonder how can I learn about it, with an emulator, an image of a real phone that can response after I finish coding a Hello world program and send it requests, for example. Perhaps later if I can afford real phones I will ask you again for more, perhaps ways to install my application into that phone,

Explain and Introduce me please.

Thank you

Comment: if u are new and learn about all tools of iphone development then u see this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#

Comment: if u required any more help hen tell me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not programing related. For iOS you need an [mac osx](http://www.apple.com/macosx/) machine and [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html) with [iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) simulator. You can create apps in the simulator with no problem.

For android you need [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I skim the Android site and visit the first program sample, I would like to know what can I do to install the Hello world on a phone (what phone name/type is that though ) ?

Comment: Depends on the sdk for adroid just put the apk in drop box and install it from there to the phone. For iOS you need to enroll to the developer program.